# Immediate UIButton rotation transform, with animated scale

Tags: swift, uibutton, transform, uianimation

I would like to animate the scale of a UIButton, and animate the scale again when completed, but have it rotate without animation. I've tried to put the rotation transform in an animation call with no duration, but somehow it still makes it part of or replace the scaling animation.

I extended the animation of the scale by a second to demonstrate the result more clearly.

```
let transforms: CGAffineTransform = .identity

button.transform = transforms

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.05, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    button.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 0.75, y: 0.75)
}, completion: { _ in

        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180)) // I want this to happen immediately, without animation

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            button.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }, completion:nil)

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the rotate `transform` to happen immediately - and it does! But then you immediately start animating it again, with respect to your `transforms` variable - reverting its current `transform` to the one in that variable.

Instead of using a variable to keep track of the button's `transform`, just refer to its current `transform`, like so:

```
button.transform = .identity
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.05, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    button.transform = button.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.75, y: 0.75)
}, completion: { _ in
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180)) // I want this to happen immediately, without animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            button.transform = button.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }, completion:nil)

})
```

Comment: Just a note if it confuses anyone - I needed to scale by 1.25 for the second scaleBy transform to adjust back to its original size.